# angularjs ng-change and bootstrap checkbox toggle not working properly

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a script like in a kendo grid and the ng-change seems that is not fired every times (in particular when the action is Yes --> No)

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="ToggleButtonTemplate">
    <input bootstrap-toggle
           type="checkbox"
           data-toggle="toggle"
           data-height="20px"
           data-width="80px"
           ng-model="data.VIEWED"
           ng-change="vm.ChangeViewedStatus(dataItem, data.VIEWED)"
           ng-checked="dataItem.VIEWED"
           data-off="{{ 'No' | translate }}"
           data-on="{{ 'Yes' | translate }}"
           data-onstyle="success"
           data-offstyle="danger" />
</script>
```

And here's the method is typescript

```
public ChangeViewedStatus(drawing: NModel.DTO_DRAWINGS, flag: boolean) {

            if (drawing != undefined) {
                this._drawing = drawing;
                var self = this;

                if (flag == undefined)
                    flag = !drawing.VIEWED;

                this.AppController.DrawingsService.SetViewedState(drawing.ID_PN_EO, drawing.ID_REVISION_EO, drawing.ID_PN, drawing.ID_PN_ISSUE, flag)

            };
        }
```

There's some known issue about that component?

Comment: why if condition to check flag? I think every time user changes checkbox state data.VIEWED is initialized with respective boolean value(true/false). why you need to apply an if condition to check if flag has something or not?

Comment: Because if i don't set that value the checkboxes are set always to false

Comment: you can initialize data.VIEWED to true/false in your controller and use that value for further calculation.